# Is there a way to get the automatically generated document ID of firebase's firestore before adding data?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to get the document ID in advance before adding!

If anyone knows how to do it, please let me know.

Comment: Yes there is, but the exact syntax depends on the platform you're developing for. Which programming language are you using?

Comment: Thank you for your comment!

Under development with react's Next.js!

Comment: For JavaScript, the flow is: `1. const newDocRef = firebase.firestore().collection("yours").doc(); 2. const newDocID = newDocRef.id; 3) newDocRef.set({ your new data });` Also see https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#add_a_document

Comment: It was very helpful!
Thank you.
I will try it based on the information you received!